# Is it correct to do t.test on accuracy scores

Tags: data-science, t-test

I have accuracy scores from two models on different datasets and languages, for example, I have this table for two models.
[image]

is it correct if I take avg accuracy from model1 and model2 and do a significance t.test on this to see what model does best on these datasets?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

Short answer is, it depends -- but it's pretty hard to do a t-test statistically on just two values. You should look into a [two-sample paired t-test](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/statistics-knowledge-portal/t-test/paired-t-test.html) to address this. Basically, is the difference between each test in model one minus model two statistically significantly different from 0 on the whole?

Best of luck!